# Please identify this 90's TV show, set in medieval times, with maybe time-travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv, medieval

We used to watch a show in school in the UK in the late 90s, set in medieval times with kings and castles... also something I remember was a device they had that created a small projection of another person (some other place or time, don't remember) that they could talk to. What was its name?

Comment: Could you please add more information? Like: Was it animated? Was it real middle ages (with scifi elements) or did it contain magic and dragons etc.?

Comment: You watched it in school - so it was an educational show?  What age was it aimed at, approximately?

Comment: Was it a British show, with actors and speech of UK origin? Or did they have accents from another country?

Comment: Did it have a bus in it? Was it Time-Busters?